# Show with the definition that the function $f:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ defined as $f(x,y,z) = (x^2-y^2+z, 4|xy|)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Show with the definition that the function $f:\mathbb{R^3} \to
>  \mathbb{R^2}$ defined as $f(x,y,z) = (x^2-y^2+z, 4|xy|)$ is
>   continuous.

Let $\alpha=(x,y,z), \alpha_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in \mathbb{R^3}$

For $\delta > 0$, $||\alpha - \alpha_0||< \delta$ $ \implies$ $$||f(\alpha)- f(\alpha_0)||$$ $$=||((x^2 - x_0^2)-(y^2-y_0^2)+(z-z_0), 4(|xy|-|x_0y_0|))||$$

Can I use the Cauchy-Scharwz inequality and use an equivalent norm, i.e. $||\cdot||_\infty$

How can I continue to cleverly develop this equality? Is there an inequality I can use to simplify or I have to develop the right side of the equality? I know I have to factorized the first few terms $(x^2 - x_0^2)$ and $(y^2-y_0^2)$ with $4(|xy|-|x_0y_0|)$

Comment: If we write $f = (f_1, f_2)$, notice that both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous.

Comment: @AaronMaroja I already know this is true, but I can't use it by the only fact that we have not seen this theorem so far in class. So I have to use the full definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the inequality $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le |x|+|y|$ and the assumption $f=(f_1,f_2)$ to see that

$$||f(\alpha)-f(\alpha_0)||\le |f_1(\alpha)-f_1(\alpha_0)|+|f_2(\alpha)-f_2(\alpha_0)|\\
\le|x^2-x_0^2|+|y^2-y_0^2|+|z-z_0|+4||xy|-|x_0y_0||\\
\le(|x|+|x_0|)|x-x_0|+(|y|+|y_0|)|y-y_0|+|z-z_0|+4|xy-x_0y_0|$$

Now $||\alpha-\alpha_0||<\delta\implies |t-t_0|<\delta$ and $|t|<|t_0|+\delta$ for $t=x,y,z$. Also note that
$$
xy-x_0y_0=x(y-y_0)+y_0(x-x_0)\\
\implies|xy-x_0y_0|\le|x||y-y_0|+y_0|x-x_0|
$$
Therefore
$$||f(\alpha)-f(\alpha_0)||<\delta(6|x_0|+6|y_0|+6\delta+1)$$
Assuming $\delta<{11\over6}$ we have
$$||f(\alpha)-f(\alpha_0)||<6\delta(|x_0|+|y_0|+2)$$
So given $\varepsilon>0$ we just have to choose
$0<\delta<\min({11\over6},{\varepsilon\over6(|x_0|+|y_0|+2)})$.